# How to Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my servers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two servers running Nodejs in the back end, both mine:

1- example.com

2- sub.example.com

Now I want to access a file of `sub.example.com` **from** another server `example.com`

But I get this error:

> GET https://sub.example.com/app/listen/1.wav net::ERR_FAILED 200
> course:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://sub.example.com/app/listen/1.wav' from origin
> 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

**In both servers I have this line:**

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ origin: (origin, callback) => callback(null, true), credentials: true }));
```

How should I fix this?

**Note: Both servers are mine.**

Comment: By reading the error, I believe you have to set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the request / in the server. (I'm not sure)

Comment: Does this "file" get served _by_ your app - or is this a request that gets handled completely by the web server itself?

Comment: @Alexxino - CORS headers are response headers, not request headers (there are CORS request headers, but these are strictly controlled by the browser)

Comment: your `cors({ origin:` would allow CORS from everywhere - is that what you want? You seemed to suggest it's just between your 2 domains

Comment: I don't get it. You have two servers 1- example.com and 2- sub.example.com and another server example.com. Are the first server and the other server the same or different servers? Can you set the headers on the other server?

Answer (score 0):

The callback in the cors config doesn't do anything, so you can get rid of it.

On the server for `example.com`:

```
app.use(cors({
    "origin": ['https://www.sub.example.com'],
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
}));
```

And for `sub.example.com`:

```
app.use(cors({
    "origin": ['https://www.example.com'],
    "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
}));
```

You can also use a wildcard `"*"` for the origin if you want to allow all sites, and modify the methods allowed.